# Visual Studio 2013 freezes constantly

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, freeze

After a few minutes regardless of what I do Visual Studio 2013 freezes and i get a popup saying "visual studio 2013 is busy". I've searched literally for hours and found nothing that relates to my problem specifically and even less so for anything that works (like repairing vs).

Comment: capture a dump of the hanging Visual Studio with ProcessExplorer, open it in DebugDiag Analyzer (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42933) and let it analyze the hang dump

Comment: The following threads in devenv.dmp are waiting in System.Threading.Monitor.Wait

( 6 )

4.17% of threads blocked (1 threads)
 
Threads waiting in Monitor.Wait  are actually waiting to re-acquire a lock which they released. The signal to reacquire the lock will be given by a call to Monitor.Pulse or Monitor.PulseAll or when the timeout is hit. 

 Look at the callstack of the thread to see which function is making a call to Monitor.Wait and then review code to find out the function which is supposed to call Monitor.Pulse or Monitor.PulseAll and see why that function is not getting called.

Comment: @magicandre1981 That's what I think is the error

Comment: do you see anything useful in the callstack?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any other solution so I refreshed my computer and that did the trick